# Asp.net Session expiring automatically after few seconds

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

When user login i am storing user_id in Session variable and on second page i am checking on page load if user_id exists then fine, otherwise redirect to sign in page but when i login and and redirected to next page after few seconds when i refresh page my session is null there and i am redirected to sign in page its happening in whole application i have tried all solutions but all in vain

Another thing is that application working fine on development server and also on local IIS in LAN but on live server this issue is occurring.

Kindly suggest solution, i am also defining session time out in minutes and mode in Proc in web.config.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an article in this topic: http://asp-net.vexedlogic.com/2012/05/23/aspasp-net-session-timeout-how-do-i-change-it/

Comment: Have you tried out of proc sessions? Maybe your server is under heavy load and getting reset

Comment: on local its working fine and also on IIS LAN its working but on deployment server session expiring after few seconds unexpectedly

Comment: Check articles on this topic: http://forums.asp.net/t/1265437.aspx/1 and http://serverfault.com/questions/372016/asp-net-session-timing-out-rapidly

Comment: no success @GauravRajput

Comment: May be sessions are disabled on your live server?? Did you check it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using InProc session state mode and multiple worker processes in the application pool then Session might expire automatically after few seconds as data loss can occur if different requests for the same session are served by different worker processes.

In my case, I am using **InProc session state mode with Maximum Worker Process set to 4** hence **session was expiring**.

Setting **Maximum Worker Process = 1 solved it**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<httpRuntime delayNotificationTimeout=""/>` in your web.config. [see more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

OR

Try this

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/loginurl" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: on local its working fine and also on IIS LAN its working but on deployment server session expiring after few seconds unexpectedly

Comment: @EhsanSajjad are you using the same web.config on development and live server?

Comment: <httpRuntime delayNotificationTimeout=""/>

what this will do ? @Amol

Comment: Not sure why you would think those web.config values would change anything related to in-proc sessions.

Answer (score 0):

try this in web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="90"></sessionState>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

One session issue I just ran into, which may help here, is that users from certain companies would have their sessions end fairly quickly but other users had no problem.  After doing a lot of testing, I found that users connecting to the website from their office were having problems but the same user connecting from home had no problem.

Their company is setup to use a single IP (or set of IPs) for all out bound web requests.  Well, this company had multiple IPs for out-site access and that IP changed (or could change) with each request.  This would reset the session on my website and log them out.

I am still in the process of implementing a fix or a check for this so I can't give you a fool proof fix, but it is something to look into.  This would explain what is happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're using a cluster of servers? Network load balancing might reroute the client to a different server every time. If so, either the NLB has to be reconfigured to keep a client on a single server or set up session sharing.

Also check that the application pool doesn't have some obscene rule to recycle itself too often.